# How to find the indices of a certain value that exists in the same location in two matrices?

Tags: python, numpy

In what I am working on, I have two numpy matrices, both the same size, filled with 0's and 1's for simplicity (but let's say it could be filled with any numbers). What I would like to know is a way to extract, from these two matrices, the position of the 1's that exist in the same position in both matrices.

For example, if I have the following two matrices and value

```py
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 0 ,1, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

b = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

value = 1
```

then I would like a way to somehow get the information of all the locations where the value "1" exists in both matrices, i.e.:

```py
result = [(0,5),(1,1),(2,3),(4,2)]
```

I guess the result could be thought of as an intersection, but in my case the position is important which is the reason I don't think np.intersect1d() would be much help. In the actual matrices I am working with, they are on the order of about 10,000 by 10,000, so this list would probably be a lot longer.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: To get the exact format that you want, use `[*zip(*np.where(a & b))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [numpy.argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

b = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

result = np.argwhere(a & b)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[0 5]
 [1 1]
 [2 3]
 [2 5]
 [4 2]]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing me to that function - that's pretty simple. To generalize this more, I was wondering how this might work though for two different arrays of values say 0-9 (rather than just 0 and 1), and I only want to know where the numbers 5 and 7 exists in both arrays. I'm assuming the proper way to go about this is to change both arrays such that any number that isn't 7 or 5 is zero, and then apply the same method as your solution. Would that by the most pythonic way of going about this?

Comment: shouldn't it be `np.argwhere((a==value)&(b==value))`?

Comment: @QuangHoang in the case of the example as is 0 and 1 not, but for the general case yes.